# Bokeh showing values in X-axis that are not in data

Tags: bokeh

> I have the following dataset and I am trying to create a scatter graph with this. However the graph has extra weeks in between although data does not have it:
>   [Input Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mE1ci.png)
>   [Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRgtY.png)

```
reset_output()
output_notebook()
data_source = ColumnDataSource(df)

p = figure(width=700, height=400,x_axis_type="datetime"
           ,toolbar_location='above',tools="save,pan,box_zoom,reset,wheel_zoom"
           ,title = 'Lead Time Comparison By Lock'
           ,x_axis_label = 'Months'
           ,y_axis_label = 'Lead Time')

p.scatter(x='Month'
          ,y='LeadTime'
          ,color=(Category10[3])[2]
         ,source=data_source)

p.xaxis.formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(days=['%m/%Y'],months=['%m/%Y'])
p.xaxis[0].ticker.desired_num_ticks = number_files
show(p)
```

Please guide

Comment: A datetime axis is a continuous, numerical axis, it will show all points in between whatever its start/end range is. In that sense, the plot is showing exactly what is expected and intended. Are you saying you want a *categorical* axis?

Comment: The question is why it is continuing in weeks , not months?

Comment: The default Datetime axis dynamically picks ticks based on the current extent of the range. The entire range interval here is ~1 month so it will pick ticks on the order of weeks in between. If the scale was a year, it would pick months in between. This is how any numerical ticker will behave. If I make a plot from x=0 to x=10 then the plot will pick ticks *in between*. This is exactly the same situation (in the span of one month, *weeks* are what are in between). You can change to a `MonthsTicker` (or other non-default ticker) if you want more control over where ticks are placed.

Comment: Maybe it is worth clarifying: the point of a numerical axis is to provide a scale to measure along. There is, in general, no expectation at all that the ticks on the axis (which are there to delineate the scale) exactly match up in any way with where all (or *any*) of the data points are. That kind of behavior is only what you would expect on a *categorical* axis, which is why I asked if what you are really after is to have a categorical axis (with each individual date as a category).